# "recognize" text from screen by intercepting wanted program calls for windows fonts

Tags: java, windows, fonts

Im quite certain that most programs use windows to output their text content to screen, which leads to relatively simple way of "reading" their content, but I haven't found anything.

Is there any ready framework for this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You've added a `java` tag, so presumably you want to do this in Java.  Are you only interested in text from Java applications?  Do you wish to "read" text in other applications or just "read" your own application's text?  If you are only interested in Java applications, are you targeting Swing applications, JavaFX applications, or both?  (For what it's worth, Swing does not "use Windows" to output text, but rather draws text with its own rendering engine.)

Comment: java tag is there because I would prefer framework for java, but I'm definitely open for everything else. As for reading - I need to read other application text, I dont need all that for my own one :).